# Cannot find name 'View'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, aurelia

This is the typescript file that we're using. There is an error on the `created(owningView: View, myView: View)` callback. It says:

> Cannot find name 'View'.

```
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';
export class Sandbox
{
    heading: string = "Sandbox";

    constructor()
    {
        console.info('constructor');
    }

    created(owningView: View, myView: View)
    {
        console.info('created');
    }

    bind(bindingContext: Object, overrideContext: Object)
    {
        console.info('bind');
    }

    attached()
    {
        console.info('attached');
    }

    detached()
    {
        console.info('detached');
    }

    unbind()
    {
        console.info('unbind');
    }
}
```

How can we tell typescript to find the `View` name?

Comment: View is a class, created for you?

Comment: @AngelAngel I think `View` is part of the Aurelia framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If View is a class created for you, you can try this:

```
export class View { // add export
    constructor()
    {
       ..//
    }
}
```

---

```
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';

import {View} from './yourPath/view' // add import view

export class Sandbox {
    heading: string = "Sandbox";
    
    ..//
}
```

---

### Update:

I do not know aurelia but looking at this:

https://github.com/aurelia/templating/blob/master/src/view.js#L27

```
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {View} from 'aurelia-templating'; // add path where you have aurelia-templating
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not importing the View class from Aurelia. This is part of the templating module in Aurelia, however, you can import it from the Aurelia Framework module as well, like so:

```
import {autoinject, View} from 'aurelia-framework';
```

That is all you are missing.